# Want to split strings when they change case

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am trying to split a string when it switches from lower case to upper case inside a word.

Example:

```
'New Hampshire, State ofColorado, State ofU.S. Court of Appeals for the D.C. CircuitDistrict of Columbia Court of AppealsMaine, State of'
```

What the split strings should look like:

```
['New Hampshire, State of', 
 'Colorado, State of', 
 'U.S. Court of Appeals for the D.C. Circuit', 
 'District of Columbia Court of Appeals',
 'Maine, State of']
```

Comment: Show some code. Have you tried to solve this yet? Is regex actually a requirement, or can you just loop through the string and split as needed?

Comment: I have edited your question to what I think you are asking - could you review it to double-check that this matches your understanding? "Parse out" is not very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split on `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` (if you are dealing only with letters `a-z` at least).

Since split in python does not allow zero width matches you could do something silly like:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', '!RANDOM!MARKER!', str).split('!RANDOM!MARKER!')
```

Comment: Did you test that? For me this doesn't split anything. (Maybe because nothing is consumed by the pattern?)

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu, you are right. *"Note that split will never split a string on an empty pattern match."* That's not like any other split in the flavors that I know of. (There appears to be several bug reports on this even.)

Comment: Using "\0" as a temporary marker may be safer. I think it's reasonable to expect that, if the string only contains the letters [a-z]|[A-Z], it doesn't contain NULL bytes.